# Is it possible to detect a continue pattern of a single wave?

Tags: wave-particle-duality

In the two-slits experiment , one photon gives an interference of two waves with their maximums.

Is it possible to seperate one of the waves ? If so, can you see a continue pattern on the print instead of a dot ?

Normally , you will see dark and light patterns because of the interference of two waves. But if only one wave can be received on a print, will you find more or less a line (wavelength) instead of a dot ( like a particle ) ?

Comment: For single photons there is one hit on a detector at an (x,y) point. , not a spread. The spread comes from many photons. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzbKb59my3U after 2'

Answer (score 3):

Every time a photon passes two slits or one slit and is detected, you obtain a dot. Indeed that's what a photon defined to be: a *particle* of light. A single photon will always be measured as a point.

You observe interference bands only when you make many many measurements of single photons crossing two slits. In fact, a laser is just that: many many photons! [Interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation)) is a property of waves. If you block one of the two slits, you obtain a [diffraction pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction).

Comment: What I meant was explicity not an interference, because in that case you get a kind of broken line with maximums etc. I don't know if it is possible, but just after the waves are created you try to seperate one wave (f.e. by bending the slit, if that is possible). Do you still gett a point?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Each photon lands on the detector as a point. There is nothing you can do to change that, unless you use a bad detector. It is only when many photons accumulate that you get a pattern. On another note, Consider that you put a mirror behind one of the two slits, so that photons going through it go onto another detector. After many photons go through, you will get two *diffraction* patterns.

Comment: Have you watched this btw? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfPeprQ7oGc. If you ignore its slightly patronising tone, it does tell you some interesting things.

Comment: I've seen the video. You sad that only after many photons you get a pattern. Is that just a matter of practicle problems or in any way? F.e. if you shoot one photon, can you see a point or not? If so why shouldn't you see a line when you succeeded in seperate one wave, so that there will be no interference. Perhaps a line which is not as bright all over the line, but it is possible to see a continuous line

Comment: That's the whole point. If you shoot one photon, you will only detect a point. Interference, no interference, slit or no slit. Light on a screen is always only absorbed photon by photon, a dot at a time. Even your digital camera work that way. That is the point of QM: energy is absorbed in packets, called quanta.

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by one photon? After all, after the slit one photon is split in two  waves which interfeer with each other. But can you still call each wave a photon?

Comment: "After the slit one photon is split in two waves which interfere with each other". This is not correct. QM is quite tricky in this respect. The "wave" that splits into two and interferes with itself is called the also called the photon's wave function, or probability amplitude. *The wave IS NOT the photon*. The photon is emitted only and detected. No wave is ever observed. The wave is a mathematical tool that gives us the probability of finding the photon at a certain point in space. This is a tricky concept and it is fundamental to properly understanding QM, you may need a book.

Comment: Ok, the wave is not a photon, the wave is a mathematical probability. But nevertheless this wave gives a pattern on the printscreen, at least when there is a interference according to you. I agree, but why can't there be a pattern of a single wave, or can it. But now at least I understand that the answer on my question is negative concerning a single photon, remains the question of a singel wave (if you can create it?)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34554/discussion-between-andrea-di-biagio-and-marijn).